# Toronto to Portland via Calgary - where to go through border security?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, air-canada, pre-clearance

I just booked an Air Canada flight from Toronto to Portland via Calgary.  My layover in Calgary is 2 hours.  I wonder if I'll be going through Customs and Border security in Toronto or in Calgary?  It can be a very time consuming process and I don't know if I'll have enough time if this will happen in Calgary.

Comment: You will be going Customs and Border security in the first place in the country or in the last when you are leaving.

Comment: If you're worried that pre-clearance in Calgary will be as time-consuming as it normally is in Toronto, don't be:  in my experience, every US pre-clearance facility in Canada takes less time than the one at Toronto Pearson.  I regularly fly out of Winnipeg (admittedly a smaller airport than Calgary) and it never takes more than about 15–20 minutes from the time that I get in line.

Answer (score 5):

US preclearance always happens at the last airport before you enter the US.  So you'll do it in Calgary.